# Zod: How to dynamically generate a schema?

Tags: typescript, zod

I desperately tried to generate a zod schema dynamically without success.

I have coded a kind of reusable form with react-hook-form, allowing me to easily create forms with various number of inputs. This component needs an array of fields, containing all the needed information to create them *(type, label, classname, etc...)*.

In order to provide my form the right types I need to provide it my fields type to the`useForm<FieldValues>()` method. That's why I need to create a schema dynamically.

```
// Schema manually coded
const schema = z.object({
    foo: z.string(),
    bar: z.number()
})

type Fields = z.infer<typeof schema>
// { foo: string; bar: number; }
```

```
// Schema dynamically generated
const fields = [
    {
        name: "foo",
        fieldType: z.string(),
        //...
    },
    {
        name: "bar",
        fieldType: z.number(),
        //...
    }
]

const generateSchemaFromFields = (fields) => {
    // ?
}

const generatedSchema = generateSchemaFromFields(fields)

type GeneratedFields = z.infer<typeof generatedSchema>
// { foo: string; bar: number; }
```

Any idea?
Thanks in advance!

*edit: I rewrote the question for clarity*

Comment: `z.object` is called with `Record<string, ZodTypeAny>`, and that means all schemas are consider as `ZodTypeAny` no matter what it was, to solve this will use lots of generic to keep the type information. And my personal suggestion is use object instead of array to store the schema in this case, it will be easier to inference the type

Comment: Any luck on this? I'm currently facing a similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understand what you want from this:

1. A parser that makes sure the values are correct according to the form's specification.
2. Helpful type inference from the schema for development.

The first should be achievable. I'll show an example below.
The second, however, might be impossible.

You wrote that the form is defined dynamically. I understand this so that the information is available at runtime. That means that `type GeneratedFields = z.infer<typeof generatedSchema>` won't help you much during development, because TypeScript doesn't know the actual definition but only all possible definitions.
As [Jerryh001](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19870522/jerryh001) mentioned, the type will be rather generic like `Record<string, any>`.

In case you just need a parser that checks the types of the form field data at runtime:

```
const fields = [
  {
    name: 'foo',
    fieldType: z.string(),
  },
  {
    name: 'bar',
    fieldType: z.number(),
  },
] as { name: string; fieldType: ZodSchema }[];

// Convert the fields definition into an object ({ [name]: fieldType })
// and turn that into a schema. Keep in mind that `name` should be unique.
const schema = z.object(
  Object.fromEntries(
    fields.map((field) => [field.name, field.fieldType])
  )
)

const validInput = { foo: 'bar', bar: 1 }
expect(schema.safeParse(validInput).success).toBe(true)

const invalidInput = { foo: 1, bar: 'err' }
expect(schema.safeParse(invalidInput).success).toBe(false)
```

The resulting schema will have a rather useless type:

```
z.ZodObject<{
    [k: string]: ZodSchema<any, z.ZodTypeDef, any>;
}, "strip", z.ZodTypeAny, {
    [x: string]: any;
}, {
    [x: string]: any;
}>
```

which is basically `Record<string, any>` but `.safeParse()` will deliver useful error messages, if anything goes wrong and you want to communicate this to the user.